# Sorting R data frame by number of factors levels

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, data.table

I have huge data frame with three columns:

```
   Surgeon Length  Surg. Date
    John    75   2015-07-06
    Max     120  2015-06-22
    Max     190  2015-01-26
    David   40   2015-11-04
    David   25   2015-04-21
    David   50   2015-12-11
    Andrey  210  2015-03-15
    Vincent 180  2015-01-30
    Vincent 180  2015-06-10
```

I would like to sort it according to how many surgeries a surgeon did. If two surgeons did the same amount of surgery, then the date of the surgery should decide the rank. 
The output should look like this:

```
   Surgeon Length  Surg. Date
    Andrey  210  2015-03-15
    John    75   2015-07-06
    Max     190  2015-01-26
    Max     120  2015-06-22
    Vincent 180  2015-01-30
    Vincent 180  2015-06-10
    David   25   2015-04-21
    David   40   2015-11-04
    David   50   2015-12-11
```

Andrey and John's name appear once in the table, so they come first, but Andrey has an earlier date, therefore he is the first in the table. Then come Max and Vincent, both with 2 surgeries. Then David with 3.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
dd <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "Surgeon Length  'Surg. Date'
John    75   2015-07-06
Max     120  2015-06-22
Max     190  2015-01-26
David   40   2015-11-04
David   25   2015-04-21
David   50   2015-12-11
Andrey  210  2015-03-15
Vincent 180  2015-01-30
Vincent 180  2015-06-10", check.names = FALSE)
```

We can set the levels of `Surgeon` such that r takes care of the ordering for us. If we tabulate the surgeons and sort the table, you can see the table names are ordered as you want, so we just set this order as the order of the `levels(Surgeon)` instead of the default (alphabetical).

Then we simply add an additional level of ordering by date.

```
sort(tbl <- table(dd$Surgeon))
 # Andrey    John     Max Vincent   David 
 #      1       1       2       2       3
```

For those with ties, we can also add a sorting factor with the first date

```
(lvls <- names(tbl)[order(tbl, tapply(as.Date(dd$`Surg. Date`), dd$Surgeon, min))])
# [1] "Andrey"    "John"  "Max"     "Vincent" "David"  

dd$Surgeon <- factor(dd$Surgeon, levels = lvls)

dd[order(dd$Surgeon, dd$`Surg. Date`), ]
#   Surgeon Length Surg. Date
# 7  Andrey    210 2015-03-15
# 1    John     75 2015-07-06
# 3     Max    190 2015-01-26
# 2     Max    120 2015-06-22
# 8 Vincent    180 2015-01-30
# 9 Vincent    180 2015-06-10
# 5   David     25 2015-04-21
# 4   David     40 2015-11-04
# 6   David     50 2015-12-11
```

with @akrun's `dplyr` solution, you can do a similar approach with more efficiency.

```
library('dplyr')
dd %>%
  group_by(Surgeon) %>%
  mutate(n=n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(n, Surgeon, `Surg. Date`) %>%
  select(-n)

#   Surgeon Length Surg. Date
#    (fctr)  (int)     (fctr)
# 1  Andrey    210 2015-03-15
# 2    John     75 2015-07-06
# 3     Max    190 2015-01-26
# 4     Max    120 2015-06-22
# 5 Vincent    180 2015-01-30
# 6 Vincent    180 2015-06-10
# 7   David     25 2015-04-21
# 8   David     40 2015-11-04
# 9   David     50 2015-12-11
```

Or if you ordered the factor levels like above, you can just do

```
dd %>% arrange(Surgeon, `Surg. Date`)
```

with `data.table`, you can still use the table/factor level approach and set keys, but I'm not sure if this is the data.table way (ie, the only overhead is the `table` which seems to be pretty fast for large vectors)

```
library('data.table')
dd$Surgeon <- factor(dd$Surgeon, levels = names(sort(table(dd$Surgeon))))
setDT(dd, key = c('Surgeon', 'Surg. Date'))

#    Surgeon Length Surg. Date
# 1:  Andrey    210 2015-03-15
# 2:    John     75 2015-07-06
# 3:     Max    190 2015-01-26
# 4:     Max    120 2015-06-22
# 5: Vincent    180 2015-01-30
# 6: Vincent    180 2015-06-10
# 7:   David     25 2015-04-21
# 8:   David     40 2015-11-04
# 9:   David     50 2015-12-11
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg  see data table edit, how would you do it?

Comment: It doesn't work when surgeons have 1 surgery, then it sorts by name and not date. For example if we switch Andrey's and John's date, still Andrey will be the first in the rank.

Comment: For the data.table approach, you can set the levels to `DT[, .(.N, min(Surg.Date)), by=Surgeon][order(N, V2), Surgeon]`

Comment: @Lanza see edits, you can just add another condition the the factor ordering and keep everything else the same